Removing mix-blend-mode from a child element in CSS
I just created an account on this forum after searching for an answer, so please forgive me if I lack the correct formatting or best practices when posting. Additionally, I am pretty new to HTML.
I am working on a personal website. I have a header with contents shown below:
<header class="nav-header">
    <a href="" class="logo">LOGO</a>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>

I have four sections for my website that alternate background colors (light, dark, light, dark). Since the header at the top is fixed, I wanted to achieve an effect where the color of the text and border at the bottom blend with the color of the background currently in view (if the background is light, the elements should be dark and vice versa). I used mix-blend-mode: difference; on the .nav-header, which works like a charm for the elements. However, I have a hover effect that changes the text color to green. The blending, when the elements are dark, turn the light text a purple color (since it's considered the difference of the original green color).
css


.nav-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 6rem;
    padding: 1rem 4rem 1rem 4rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E1E1E1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    background: transparent;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}




I have tried setting the mix-blend-mode for the element as well as the hover effect, but that does not work:

.nav-header a:hover {
    color: #6A9955;
    mix-blend-mode: normal;
}


I have tried to use the isolation property for the elements, but that was no use as well.

How can I ignore/remove a mix-blend-mode setting on a parent element to maintain a color-change hover effect on a child element? Thank you for your help and consideration.

Perhaps you can add your other CSS code that is relavent as I am unable to recreate any issue. If I style a colored logo and place a mix-blend-mode on it with difference, then using your code on hover, it renders properly. I even did JS mouseover, mouseout to test the computedStyle and getPropertyValue and it toggles between difference and normal... https://codepen.io/dlandry7/pen/rNXxzPY

Thank you for your reply! I see what you did. This is so strange. The only difference is that I am using text as buttons, which may have something to do with it. Could this be the problem?

Can you put an example in your question that shows what you have attempted exactly?

My apologies for the delayed response. I took the same structure you had and applied all of my elements (without size and proportions) codepen.io/smeya/pen/GRVoyBa
Here, I am achieving the result I want. However, on my website, the text, when hovered over (and is in front of a white background), turns to purple instead of green (because of the difference).

I have found the problem. I changed the codepen to use the correct background color for what I am talking about (to a very light grey). This is causing the original green to turn into a purple color. This is revealing that the mix-blend-mode set on the .nav-header cannot be overridden by rewriting the mix-blend-mode on the .nav-header a to normal, so I am not sure how to approach this.
